# Identify the current page name

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, pagereference

In my apex controller how can I find out what my current page name is? I have need where I am redirecting from one page to another. 
My first page does not have any parameters but my 2nd page has a parameter. I am using the same controller for both the pages. So when 
I try to get the parameter name(part of page2) in constructor when page1 is loaded I get a null pointer exception because there is no parameter
for page1

I tried this but does not seem to work. Here page2 has a parameter called param1 and Page1 has no parameters. When the page1 is loaded first it goes to else condition and 
throws a null pointer exception when I try to get that parameter:

```
if(ApexPages.currentPage() == Page.page1){
// do nothing

}else{
objectName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
Amethod(objectName);
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the URL to get the name of the current page.

```
String pageName = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl()
    .substringAfter('/apex/').substringBefore('?');
```

Comment: Bravo! Just what I wanted:)